# powershell permissions

Tags: powershell, acl

I am currently using this to get a list of all permissions for specific folders.

```
`$InputFile = "C:\temp\Folders.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\temp\FolderPermissions.txt"
$FolderList = Get-Content $InputFile

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList)
{
    Get-Acl $folder | Format-list >>$OutputFile
    } 

`
```

What i would like is for it to then remove all access apart from administrator from each of the specified folders.

I have looked at using SetAccessControl but can only manage to get it to remove all.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code will remove any user execpt users matching 'administrator'
If you want to add more accounts add it to the `Where-Object` filter, for example:

`Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -match 'Administrator' -or $_.IdentityReference -eq 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'}`

```
$InputFile = "C:\temp\Folders.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\temp\FolderPermissions.txt"
$FolderList = Get-Content $InputFile

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList)
{
Get-Acl $folder | Format-list >>$OutputFile

### Remove all ACL Rules exepet 'Administrator(s)'

$ACL = Get-ACL -Path $Folder
$Rules = $ACL.Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -notmatch 'Administrator'}

    Foreach ($Rule in $Rules)
    {
    [Void]$ACL.RemoveAccessRule($Rule)
    }
    Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl

}
```

Comment: Going to give this a try now, fantastic. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but is there anyway to have it only change the permissions on the specified folder and not recursively

Comment: they are quite random but have huge amounts of folders within, and can take hours per folder. I need it just to impact the one folder